# How to incorporate video with parallax?

Tags: html, css, parallax

I made a parallax website that works successfully. However, when I incorporate the video, the parallax effect is lost because, for some reason, the video is considered foreground instead of background. I tried playing with the z-index but that hasn't amounted to anything.

Here is my code, thanks!

```
<div id="VideoContainer">
    <video autoplay="autoplay" id="Video" loop="loop" preload="auto" width="100%">
        <source src="desktop.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>

#VideoContainer {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you put the non-working example with some of your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: What browser(s)?  The way video is implemented may make this tricky.

Comment: Unless it's a big video you should consider making it an animated gif.. will improve page speed, compatibility, and solve your problem.

Comment: @evanwong Sorry, but for some reason the parallax isn't working on the jsfiddle :/

Comment: @Brad I'm using the latest version of Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @dcc So is your suggestion to do something like this: `background: url(../video.gif) 50% 0  no-repeat fixed;` ?

Comment: Thanks for all of the help everyone! Actually, I tried the gif solution and it worked :)

Comment: @dcc What are you talking about?  Videos are almost always smaller than their equivalent gif files, and will offer higher quality.